# Rewrite subdirectory to subdomain using wildcard htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, wildcard

How to rewrite this

mywebsite.com/storage/exports/1-folder1 to folder1.mywebsite.com/

mywebsite.com/storage/exports/2-folder2 to folder2.mywebsite.com/

mywebsite.com/storage/exports/3-folder3 to folder3.mywebsite.com/

.......

using wildcard htaccess

THanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` in your web root `/` directory

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+storage/exports/([^/]+)(/.*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.mywebsite.com%2 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /storage/exports/%1/$1 [L]
```

This requires your sub-directories to **not** be numbered because, unless I know what the exact sub-domain names are, I cannot infer the ordinals correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the subdomain name is folder1,folder2,folder3,... that will be dynamic whenever there is a new folder create, the folder will auto display as subdomain name

Comment: Yes it will work for any subdomain but it will redirect **subdomain.mywebsite.com** to the directory with the **same** name i.e. it will redirect to **/storage/exports/subdomain** and **not** /storage/exports/1-subdomain.